# HttpUrlConnection is not going

Tags: php, android, post

I'm trying to make a post request in android to php but it is not going 
 here is my code...

```
package bk.girl;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void sendRequest(View view)
    {

        try
        {
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8")
                    + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("bk", "UTF-8");
            URL url=new URL("http://bharath.myartsonline.com/father.php");
            URLConnection con=url.openConnection();
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter os=new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
            os.write(data);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Here is my xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/styles"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="bk.girl.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send"
            android:onClick="sendRequest"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have added Internet permission in manifest file too even then the request is not going...

here is my php script...

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
file_put_contents("file.html", $name);
?>
```

The file in server is not creating ...Plz help..

Comment: `catch (Exception e){}
    }` How do you know if there is an exception or not? And how do you inform the user? You should better look at some code examples as you can do better.

Comment: The php file is not echo()ing anything. And you also do not try to read echos. So you never know what the script does. Look at more example code as you can do much better.

Comment: `extract($_POST);`. What should that function do?

Comment: `sendRequest()`. You cannot call that function in an onClick handler. You have a NetworkOnMainThread exception clearly visible in the logcat. And your app crashes. Which you did not report. Why not?

Comment: Is it a must to use networking in an async task ? and by the way extract($_POST) extracts all the variables in the $_POST super global variable...so you need not define $_POST['name']=$name like that....